Intermittent TABLE ALREADY EXISTS database error
In CakePHP 4.3.3 with SQLite I use a temporary table which I refresh by deleting and re-creating. Occasionally from the CREATE statement I get an error that the table already exists, despite that my code is:
$connection->execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_positions_on_date')->fetchAll();
$query = $this->build_positions_on_date_query($date, $account_id, null, $security_id);
$connection->execute('CREATE TABLE tmp_positions_on_date AS ' . $query);

$query holds the table definition.
It only happens every several hundred queries or so (months can go by between errors). This is a single-user system without competing processes trying to get to the database.
For now, I've tried wrapping the DELETE query in a transaction to see if that solves it.

Use CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ...?

Possibly.  I'd like to know what's going on.  I could try this but it might be 3 months before it trips over itself again.
